# Swap the 2nd character with the next-to-last

Tags: c, string

I have to change the 2nd letter with penultimate letter for word with more than 3 letters. 
Example i have this string: Alex are mere
The result should be: Aelx are mree
But i get this when i run my program: Axel` aler

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n,j=0;
    char text[81],cuv[44],l;

    printf("Introduce-ti textul:");
    gets(text);

    for(i=0;i<strlen(text);i++)
    {
        if(text[i] != 32) {
            cuv[j]=text[i];
            j += 1;
        } else {
            n = strlen(cuv) - 1;

            l= cuv[1];
            cuv[1]=cuv[n-1];
            cuv[n-1]=l;

            printf("%s ",cuv);
            strcpy(cuv,"");
            j=0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to "*swap the 2nd character with the next-to-last*" is an easier way of phrasing the question.

Comment: FIrst split full sentence in word and after that check every word length is greater than three and then replace the caharcter.

Comment: `strlen(cuv) - 1;` won't work - `cuv` isn't null-terminated.

Comment: You might like to read this http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to learn to help yourself in such cases.

Comment: What cad means is put `cuv[j]='\0';` before the `n=strlen(cuv)-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do not want to use `gets`. It was removed from the standard library because it was unsafe, use `fgets` instead. That being said, all you need to do is tokenize your input string into words, and then if the word is greater than 3 chars, swap the 2nd and next to last characters. One way would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 256
#define MAXW  64

int main (void) {

    size_t len;
    char str[MAXS] = {0};
    char word[MAXW] = {0};
    char *p = NULL;

    fgets (str, MAXS, stdin);   /* read input from stdin */

    /* tokenize string */
    for (p = strtok (str, " "); p; p = strtok (NULL, " \n")) 
    {
        strncpy (word, p, MAXW - 1);    /* copy token to word */

        if ((len = strlen (word)) > 3)  /* if word > 3 */
        {
            char tmp = word[1];         /* swap 2nd & next to last */
            word[1] = word[len-2];
            word[len-2] = tmp;
        }
        printf ("%s ", word);        
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ printf "Alex are mere\n" | ./bin/swap2nd
Aelx are mree
```

or if you wanted to enter the text:

```
$ ./bin/swap2nd
Alex are mere
Aelx are mree
```

**Second Method Using Start/End Pointers**

You can also modify the original string ready be `fgets` in place by using nothing more than a *start-pointer* (`p` below) and *end-pointer* (`ep` below) to work your way down the string character-by-character, stopping each time the *end-pointer* points to a `space`, `tab`, or `newline` and then using the difference between the *start* and *end* pointers to check the length of the word and perform the character swap if the length is greater than 3 chars. You can work through each version and compare:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXS 256

int main (void) {

    char str[MAXS] = {0};
    char *p = NULL;
    char *ep = NULL;

    fgets (str, MAXS, stdin);   /* read input from stdin */

    p = ep = str;

    while (*ep) /* for each char, if a space, tab or newline */
        if (*ep == ' ' || *ep == '\t' || *ep == '\n') {
            if ((ep - p) > 3) {         /* if length > 3 */
                char tmp = *(p + 1);    /* swap chars    */
                *(p + 1) = *(ep - 2);
                *(ep - 2) = tmp;
            }
            p = ++ep;   /* set p to next word */
        }
        else
            ++ep;

    printf ("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/swap2nd2
Alex are mere
Aelx are mree
```

Which approach you choose between these two methods, as well as the method posted by Vlad, is largely a matter of taste/choice. All are valid and are just different way of accomplishing the same thing. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "Alex Chiurtu";
    char t[sizeof( s )];

    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

    do
    {
        t[i] = s[i];
        if ( s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '\t' && s[i] != '\0' )
        {
            ++j;
        }
        else if ( j != 0 )
        {            
            if ( j > 3 )
            {                
                char c = t[i-j + 1];
                t[i-j+1] = t[i-2];
                t[i-2] = c;
            }

            j = 0;
        }
    } while ( s[i++] );        


    puts( s );
    puts( t );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Alex Chiurtu
Aelx Ctiurhu
```

Take into account that function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard any more.

Also it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like `32`. Its meaning is unclear.

In your program array `cuv` was not zero initialized therefore the following statement

```
n = strlen(cuv) - 1;
```

results in undefined behaviour of the program. Also it is not a good idea each time to calculate the length of the string.